Prove $G$ has an orientation such all the triangles are cyclic iff $G$ has no subgraph isomorphic to $K_4$
Here cyclic triangle means directed triangle.
First note we can not orient $K_4$ such that all the triangles are cyclic. (I do not know the reason why, I just tried to greedily finding one but it does not exist) So does any graph with $K_4$ as subgraph.
Conversely, I try to show by induction.
$n=3$, trivial.
Suppose we have $n=k$, now $G$ has $k+1$ vertices, delete any of the vertex $v$. Then there is an orientation of $G-v$ such that all the triangles are cyclic. Adding back $v$, we may have more triangles and each of these new triangles must have two edges incident to $v$. Obviously we can orient them to be cyclic.
Am I right proving in this way?

It is not so obvious. Any of these edges incident to $v$ can belong to more than one triangle. Why should the orientations of these different triangles not conflict?

You are right. I forgot that.

But you can use that. If $G$ does not contain $K_4$ then the conflicts may be solvable.

I think $G$ must have a vertex of degree at most 2 and if so, our problems are solvable. But do not see the reason.

$G$ does not need to have a vertex of low degree; for example, $K_{n/2,n/2}$ has high degree and no copies of $K_4$. (It also doesn't have any triangles, so the problem becomes very easy.)

A five cycle plus an vertex connecting them all is a counter example.
